# Why do I need to use finally to close resources?

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

Most of the time, the only thing I see a finally block used for is something like

```
FileInputStream f;
try{
    f= new FileInputStream("sample.txt");
    //something that uses f and sometimes throws an exception
}
catch(IOException ex){
    /* Handle it somehow */
}
finally{
    f.close();
}
```

My question is, if f's scope ends with the enclosing block, why do we need to close it in the finally?

Comment: In your case, `f`'s scope does not end with the try-block

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: This is clearly a readable example.

Comment: Creating a File reference doesn't throw exceptions (or create a file handle), for future reference.

Comment: FWIW, in Java 7, you can use the try-with-resources construct:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because garbage collection is *not* the same thing as resource cleanup.

For example, if you have a JDBC Connection object that goes out of scope, there's no signal sent to the database server to indicate that open cursors and connections are no longer needed.  Without those messages, you'll eventually exhaust the number of cursors and connections available to you.

Same with file handles and any other resource.  Clean up after thyself.

Comment: Because the code in the finally block is guaranteed to be executed, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Joe good example.  But never return something in a finally block if you have a catch block which throw an exception.  in that case, your exception will never be thrown...  i learn this one the hard way ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Well you've given a bad example - I suspect you meant something like `FileInputStream` - but the basic reason is that Java doesn't have deterministic finalization.

The scope of the *variable* `f` ends with the block it's declared in (not the `try` block), but that doesn't mean there are necessarily no "live" references to the object any more - and the garbage collector will neither finalize the object nor garbage collect it in any deterministic manner.

Unless you want to leave resources hanging around for an arbitrary length of time (and delay garbage collection, as finalizers require an extra round of collection before the memory is finally released), you should explicitly close resources.

Basically Java does *not* support RAII in the same way that C++ does; you shouldn't try to use it as if it were C++.

Comment: Edited to reflect your suggestion: I was just coming up with a Closeable from memory, so thanks for giving me one that actually applies :P

Answer (score 2):

because finally is called everytime, even if you get an exception raised.  the finally block insure you that the file/connection will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Java doesn't guarantee that an object will be garbage-collected as soon as a particular reference to it falls out of scope. So for objects that reference limited system resources, such as a file descriptor, it's not enough to wait for garbage collection.

Note though, that `java.io.File` is not actually such an object.

Answer (score 0):

We handled exception by try catch finally ,finally block every time execute but there is no guarantee of catch because catch block execute only if exception passed in parameter matched.
For example if we have open any database connection so it is must we closed it before leave,tht must be implemented into finally.